# Angular lazy loading module depending on config service

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I have a config.service which loads a config.json file on APP_INITIALIZATION (with APP_INITIALIZER). In my app-routing.module.ts I need to access this configuration and decide depending on the content whether to load one or another module. The config can be accessed by the service like this:

```
this.configService.getConfig('KEY')
```

Therefore I need something like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: this.configService.getConfig('enabled') ? () => import('./one-module/one-module.module').then((m) => m.OneModule) : () => import('./another-module/another-module.module').then((m) => m.AnotherModule)
  }
];
```

Is that possible to achieve?

Comment: Why not redesign into taking advantage of canLoad guard and routing to a better path if not ?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/router/CanLoad